# How to put column values in variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `#SqlData` with the following column `splitdata`.

```
splitdata
---------
BB10_1_X
4759
566549
```

I want to store these 3 column values into 3 different variables. Please help me as I am a beginner and I don't know how to do it..

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by variable? Is your table currently in SQL? If so, what are the columns? If not, in what format are your data currently stored? What all have you tried so far?

Comment: i have modified the question. I hope it will help. thnakns

Comment: This appears as to be a follow-up to stackoverflow.com/questions/23088022/…, but I'm not sure its the right idea. That is, you'l only get this sort of arbitrary #SqlData temp table if you are are splitting your source into rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare variables like this:

```
DECLARE @Var AS VARCHAR(MAX)
```

And you can assign them using a select statement like this:

```
SELECT @Var=MyColumn 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE <My Condition>
```

There are plenty of resources on `TSQL` if you google it.

In your situation, if you're sure you will have exactly three rows, you can use three separate select statements:

```
DECLARE @Var1 AS VARCHAR(MAX), @Var2 AS VARCHAR(MAX), @Var3 AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Var1=MyColumn 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE <My Condition That Returns First Row>

SELECT @Var2=MyColumn 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE <My Condition That Returns Second Row>

SELECT @Var3=MyColumn 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE <My Condition That Returns Third Row>
```